# jenkins choose node which use to run task

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 nodes into Jenkins to run concrete project's parametrized task. These is automation test suite and 2 machines prepared to run this parametrized task.

I want to have ability to choose which slave machine use for concrete run (for concrete set of parameters) of the task.

I thought that I can do it with Node parameter in the task.

At the moment when default slave is running parametrized task executes only on default slave.

But I want to choose which slave I will use for run.

Could you please advise me way to perform this task?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way it to have two jobs for that -
one for each slave, with the relevant parameters to run.

Another method:

1. Learn to use Jenkins' **[Multi-Configuration Projects](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)**
2. Set a *Matrix-Job* that will run on all relevant slave
3. Set a parameter on the job that will hold the target slave to run on
   (could be a drop-down list of relevant hosts - let's name it `RUN_ON_HOST`)
4. In the *Execute Shell* block, check if the host you are on is equal to `RUN_ON_HOST`,
   and if NOT - exit without error (`exit 0`).

This will

Comment: Yes, I know this way. 


But I want to implement another one. I want to choose which machine to use for test suite directly before launch the test. Without any additional steps to create labels, shutdown machine, etc.

I got that my way looks like wrong of Jenkins philosophy. But I want to implement exactly this way because of some reasons.

Comment: OK - added another solution - Matrix Job Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done via specifying Node/Label as a parameter provided by [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

You can specify labels as well as node name directly in the field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide on how to choose a node before Jenkins runs the job.

https://thetechtinker.com/how-to-choose-a-node-before-running-a-jenkins-pipeline/

As said in the guide, you can do it via the Jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile) or via the Node and Label Parameter plugin.